# Boolean Expression x'y + x(x + y')

Tags: boolean-algebra

I'm still learning Boolean Algebra so I apologise if the question seems pretty straight forward. After working on this problem I thought the answer was 'x', my working out was:

x'y + x(x + y')

= x'y + xx + xy'

= x'y + x + xy'

= x + xy'

= x

but after runnng this through a logic circuit I realise if x = 0 and y = 1 then the ouput does not equal x.
Can someone help me simplify this expression

Comment: You lost the $x'y$ from the 3rd to the 4th line.

Comment: Yeah I thought I could simplfy that but turns out I cant

Comment: Maybe you wanted to apply something similar as in your last step. There it works because $x+xy' = x(1+y') \stackrel{1+y' = 1}{=} x$. But from the 3rd to the 4th line the situation is different.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You correct until the step

> x'y + x + xy' = x + xy'

But you can go from there and see that `x'y + xy' = x ⊕ y`.

This follows since `x'y = 1 ⇒ x=0, y=1` and `xy' = 1 ⇒ x=1, y=0`.

Following this `x ⊕ y + x` can be simplified.

> x ⊕ y + x = x + y

With your final solution **x'y + x(x + y') = x + y.**

Answer (score 1):

Two really useful principles are:

**Absorption**

$x(x+y)=x$

$x+xy=x$

**Reduction**

$x(x'+y)=xy$

$x+x'y=x+y$

With those:

$x'y+x(x+y')\overset{Absorption}{=} x'y+x\overset{Reduction}{=} y+x$